# Remove repeated characters from the beginning of a string in Bash

Tags: bash

I would like to remove repeated `z`'s from string start like (not anchored):

```
string="zzz is cool"
echo ${string//"z"/""}
#is cool
```

I try to anchor at the start with pattern matching:

```
echo ${string##z}
#zz is cool
```

which I expect to remove longest occurrence of `z`. However the result is somewhat "unexpected" (not `" is cool"`).

Why? And how to get the expected result with bash pattern matching?

Comment: That is the longest occurrence of the single character `z`.

Comment: @glennjackman Part of question was what constitutes a `pattern` in pattern matching

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a glob like

```
shopt -s extglob
echo ${string##+(z)}
# => is cool
```

See [*Pattern matching*](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-string-manipulation#2-pattern-matching):

> There’s also an extended matching system called “extended globbing”. It enables us to constraint wildcards to specific patterns:
>
> `*(pattern)` – matches any number of occurrence of pattern
> `?(pattern)` – matches zero or one occurrence of pattern
> `+(pattern)` – matches one or more occurrence of pattern
> `!(pattern)` – negates the pattern, matches anything that doesn’t match the pattern
>
> Extended globbing must be turned on with the [shopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) command.

Comment: FYI, shopt has some confusing bits, so if you're in a shell script you probably want to do `$(shopt -s extglob; echo "${string##+(z)}")`

Answer (score 1):

You can, but don't have to use an extglob for such a simple operation.

```
$ string='zzz is cool'
$ echo "${string#"${string%%[!z]*}"}"
 is cool
```

Answer (score 0):

Use space as delimeter

```
$ echo ${string#* }
is cool
```